# Prove that convergent sequence converges in 0

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> The convergent sequence $(a_n)$ is such that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is $a_n$ such that $|a_n-0|<\epsilon$. Prove that $(a_n)$ converges in $0$.

edit: it's false.

This is a problem I made up, so I am not sure if it's true. Can my proof be criticized? I think there is an easier way of doing it.

Let $(a_n)$ converge in $a$. From the definition: for all $\epsilon>0$ there is $N_\epsilon$ such that $n\geq N_\epsilon$ implies $|a-a_n|<\epsilon$, in particular, assuming $a\neq 0$, there is such $N$ for $\epsilon=|\frac{a}{2}|>0$. From the hypothesis it also exists $a_m$ such that $|a_m|< \epsilon=|\frac{a}{2}|$. The claim is that there is $m$ such that $a_m$ satisfies both conditions, leading to contradiction.
This choice of $m$ would imply in

$\epsilon=|\frac{a}{2}|>|a-a_m|\geq||a|-|a_m||\geq|a|-|a_m|>|a|-|\frac{a}{2}|=\epsilon$.

(I used the relations $|x-y|\geq||x|-|y||$ and $|z|\geq z$) Contradiction in "supposing $a\neq 0$".

Proof of the claim($m$ exists):

> If the non-empty set $\left\{|a_m|:|a_m|< |\frac{a}{2}|,\ a_m\in(a_n)\right\}$ was finite, then for $\epsilon$ equal to its smallest element there would be no $|a_n|$ smaller than $\epsilon$ for all $n$, which contradicts the hypothesis. So the set is not finite and not empty: there are infinitely many integers $m$, and a $m\geq N$ exists.

Comment: What about the sequence $a = (0,1,1,1,1,1,\dots)$? It satisfies your assumption but does not converge to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment points out, the claim is false:  the sequence $(1,0,1,0,\ldots)$ satisfies your claim but does not converge to $0$. Note that in your $m$ exists proof, the set you considered is the set of values that the terms in the sequence can take, not the indices, so it is possible that your smallest element is $0$ (consider the above counterexample). In this case, your contradiction argument will not work since you are letting $\epsilon = 0$.